# MS SQL Insert race condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to write a stored procedure that will insert only unique values to a table. Let me show sample code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertSp]  (
    @memberId INT
) AS

BEGIN
   INSERT INTO [dbo].[Members] (memberId)
   SELECT @memberId
   WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT memberId 
    FROM [dbo].[Members] WITH (UPDLOCK)
    WHERE memberId = @memberId)
END
```

But what happen if there are many calls that tries to insert the same value at the same time. Do i need a transaction, or NOT EXISTS check is enough for me?

Comment: Make sure you've also, at a minimum, applied a `UNIQUE` constraint on that column. Even if your code is wrong, it ensures you don't end up with broken data.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever but i want to not receive exceptions, can i make sure there will be not duplicate inserts without constraints, or that's the best practice to add constraints and add TRY CATCH ?

Comment: Just use the sql server equivalent for INSERT IGNORE from mysql

Comment: Personally, yes, I'd just have the constraint and catch the error. You *should* have the constraint to prevent any "whoops" moments, and once the constraint is in place, the server's going to perform the equivalent check anyway, so any additional checks done by your code are extraneous.